# GWTP: redirect to another page given condition

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

Got this app, if you open it the first time it will check for a value in a DB, if the value is there all is good

If the value is NOT there, I would like to redirect to another page where the user can input this.

How can I do this?

PS: I can access to the other page using the @NameTolen value in the URL. Just don't know how to make an automatic "switch" and in which part of the Presenter layer to code it (if it even goes there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your presenter you can check the value in `onReveal()` or `onReset()` methods. See presenter life cycle: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Presenter_lifecycle

You also need to inject the `PlaceManager` in the presenter using the constructor. And then you can redirect like that:

```
public void onReveal() {
  if(checkValue()) {
    PlaceRequest myRequest = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.yourPage);
    placeManager.revealPlace(myRequest);
  }
}
```

See Revealing a Presenter: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Revealing_a_presenter

Comment: oh, that is what those methods are for :), I'll come back to you, thx

Answer (score 1):

You could do it even before revealing the presenter. 
In `prepareFromRequest`, you can call the dispatcher and in the callback decide where to "redirect".

```
  @Override
  public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request) {
    super.prepareFromRequest(request);
    dispatcher.execute( new GetData(), 
        new AsyncCallback<GetDataResult>(){
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(GetDataResult result) {
            // depending on result reveal another place
            placeManager.revealPlace( ... )
          }
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // Display an error message
          }
        } ) );
  }
```

Also see here for more ideas:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Using_manual_reveal